# How to check the pattern for password before Form Submit angular JS 1.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have password and confirm password fields. I have a directive where it will check for the passwords match. Once the passwords are matching am enabling the submit button.

But I need to handle some conditions along with password match scenario.

Additional Conditions to be handled:

1. It should not contain more than 3 repeating numbers.
2. It should not contain numbers in order (Example : 1234, 5678, 2345 etc..)
3. It should allow only numbers.(Specail characters, alphabets, spaces should not allowed.)

This is what I tried:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="cPswd">
   <form id="form" autocomplete="off" name="form" novalidate>
      <div>
         <label for="password">password</label>
         <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" maxlength=4 ng-model="pwd.password" required />
      </div>
      <div>
         <label for="cpassword">confirm password</label>
         <input id="cpassword" name="cpassword" type="password" value="" maxlength=4 ng-model="pwd.cpassword" compare-to="pwd.password" required />
      </div>
      <button ng-disabled="form.$invalid">Submit</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

**Compare Password Directive:**

```
angular.module('app.module').directive('compareTo',compareTo);

function compareTo(){
        return {
          require: "ngModel",
          scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
              return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
            };

            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
              ngModel.$validate();
            });
          }
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('app.module').controller('cPswd',['$scope', function($scope){
 $scope.pwd = {
   password: "",
   cpassword: ""
 };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS has a validation attribute directive called [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

I'm no expert on Regular Expressions, but with little research I'm sure you could find a Regex that fits your validation needs.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is definitely the a nice idea. You can use the HTML Input's pattern attribute with Angular like this:

```
<input type="password" ng-pattern="^(?!.*([0-9])\1{3})[0-9]+$" />
```

This will make sure the user entered only numbers and none of them repeating more than three times. I cannot figure out how to exclude ordered numbers though, sorry.